# IIS Save data in App Pool Variable shared across other servers

Tags: iis, load-balancing, application-pool

I create one application and after login saving the data in a variable inside application pool variable now the problem is when i am going to load balancer the other server doesn't have this data.

Please help

Comment: There is nothing called "application pool variable". Do you mean sessions?

Comment: @LexLi Yes sessions in app pool

Comment: Then you should learn different session modes and choose one that can go beyond process boundary.